# LED power supply with no ground, on what looks like a GFCI breaker

Tags: electrical, grounding, led

I am installing 12V LED strip lighting in 5 closets of my home. My intention is to use a single [Mean Well HLG-185H-12A](https://www.ledsupply.com/power-supplies/mean-well-hlg-series) power supply in the attic, and then run low voltage wire to each closet through a fuse box.

The plastic junction box I intended to tap into (and mount the power supply above) is fed by old wiring and is ungrounded. LED light fixtures in my bathroom are fed by the same circuit. Will these new strip lights be any more unsafe? Is contact with the power supply box the main risk?

I also noticed that the breaker for this circuit has a *Test* button, which I assume means GFCI or AFCI. Does this mitigate the lack of grounding in this case?

[image: The junction box]
[image: Install plan]
[image: The breaker]

Comment: In that photo, it appears there are black wires, white wires, and bare copper wires. Is that bare wire only on the new stretch of cable? If so, then I'd look for LED light-strips that are **double insulated**, and have *no* metal parts that can be touched. That said, in many locales, one must update old, out-of-code wiring when making *any* change to it.

Comment: That bare copper is just the new stretch that was put in to LED lights in our bathroom remodel. The work was inspected, fwiw.

Comment: Is double insultated LED strip needed with a GFCI breaker?

Comment: A GFCI helps, and double-insulation makes it safer.

Comment: The "kitchen plugs" aka small appliance circuits are specifically not supposed to be shared outside of the kitchen (with some slack for dining room) so the stuff apparently added after the initial labeling is not really supposed to be on this circuit.

Comment: Also - does that junction box have a cover that was removed for the picture, or is it just sitting open up there in the attic?

Comment: I took it off for the picture 

Comment: "Will these new strip lights be any more unsafe?" Than what? While grounding is _required_ on all new circuits, including lighting, many built in (permanent vs plug-in) light fixtures aren't grounded.

Comment: Any more unsafe than the existing LED lights on this circuit. Particularly because of the size of the power supply.